# Create average boundary between raster classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, boundaries

I have a raster with multiple fields in it representing glaciers. As the boundary between land and ice is not often strict, there are little ice fields outside the end of the glacier. I do a raster classification and get it delimited.

Now I would like to estimate mean height of this boundary, and for it I need a line feature. How can I extract an average position from it? I may be confusing, but I think a picture will explain it well:

[image]

The boundary doesn't need to be a straight line, but it needs to be a single line. So I can't just calculate circumference of classes.

I'm using ArcGIS/arcpy and open source (QGIS, Gdal).

Comment: There are more ice above any section within extent shown

Comment: Well, you're obviously right, thank you. Is it clear what I mean though? More ice/ground within nearest neighborhood. Something like "no less than 90% of area above the line must be ice" - I can't give an exact solution because I'm actually looking for it.

Comment: Perhaps tabulate area can help. Reclassify elevation into reasonable intervals, e.g. 50 m and tabulate areas. At some elevation the ratio will exceed threshold

Comment: Thanks! I made it using tabulation. Afterwards I only needed to create some join, spatial join and summarize functions. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps tabulate area can help. Reclassify elevation into reasonable intervals, e.g. 50 m and tabulate areas. At some elevation the ratio of cells count belonging to different classes will exceed threshold.

If intervals are too small consider using accumulated values of cells count versus elevation. This is essentially an old school 1D approach widely used in glaciology when no GIS was available at all.